# js-shown elements aren't accessible for some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, form-submit, show-hide

I have several buttons in the table (one button for each row) and show/hide them using jQuery:

```
$('#some-id tr').hover(
    function() { $(this).find('.button-class').removeAttr('disabled').css(...); },
    function() { $(this).find('.button-class').attr('disabled', true).css(...); }
);
```

It properly works for showing/hiding.
The catch is sometimes shown buttons aren't accessible from the browser (don't react to left and right clicks, browsers don't show tooltip). Could be liven up by right click on the rest of browser window (not always).

Tested in Firefox and Chrome.

**SOLVED?** Very interesting. `.css(...)` in the code above are contained setting `background: none/url(image.png)`. Buttons have no text, so were invisible with `disabled="disabled"` and  `background: none;`. I tried simply `.show()/.hide()` and can't reproduce the problem. Great, but what was wrong with the first edition except of its redundancy?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you wrap your code in jQuery's `.ready()` function, or some other such function, such as `$(window).load()`.

Here's how it would look with `.ready()`:

```
$(function() {
     $('#some-id tr').hover(
         function() { $(this).find('.button-class').removeAttr('disabled').css(...); },
         function() { $(this).find('.button-class').attr('disabled', true).css(...); }
     );
});
```